# How to append new profile to configtx.yaml file using shell script?

Tags: yaml, hyperledger-fabric, yq

I am new to shell scripting and trying to explore the same. The requirement is as follows. I need to write a script file where I get the channelProfile name dynamically from the frontend, and for this channelProfile I have to append the existing TwoOrgsChannel, under the Profiles section of configtx.yaml file. I have configtx.yaml file with the profiles section defined as :

```
            Profiles:
            TwoOrgsChannel:
                     Consortium: SampleConsortium
                     <<: *ChannelDefaults
                     Application:
                         <<: *ApplicationDefaults
                         Organizations:
                             - *Org1
                             - *Org2
                         Capabilities:
                           <<: *ApplicationCapabilities
```

Note:*ChannelDefaults,*ApplicationDefaults,*ApplicationCapabilities are defined in the same file(configtx.yaml).

The output should look like this:

```
            Profiles:
            TwoOrgsChannel:
                     Consortium: SampleConsortium
                     <<: *ChannelDefaults
                     Application:
                         <<: *ApplicationDefaults
                         Organizations:
                             - *Org1
                             - *Org2
                         Capabilities:
                           <<: *ApplicationCapabilities
        FiveOrgsChannel:
                     Consortium: SampleConsortium
                     <<: *ChannelDefaults
                     Application:
                         <<: *ApplicationDefaults
                         Organizations:
                             - *Org1
                             - *Org2
                         Capabilities:
                           <<: *ApplicationCapabilities
```

This is the code I am trying to implement but not able to generate the expected output.

```
            export CONFIGTXFILE=$1
            export CHANNELPROFILE=$2
             
            yq r --prettyPrint -j $ CONFIGTXFILE > peer.json 
            jq --arg e "${CONFIGTXFILE}" ".Profiles += ${CHANNELPROFILE} Profiles.TwoOrgsChannel " peer.json > mypeer.json
            
            yq r --prettyPrint mypeer.json > configtx.yaml
```

When i run this file , i’m getting this error.

```
            div@DESKTOP-0BSERCC:/mnt/c/Users/Div/Downloads/fabric-samples_3/first-network$ ./scriptFile.sh configtx.yaml FiveOrgsChannel
            jq: error: FiveOrgsChannel/0 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:
            .Profiles += FiveOrgsChannel, Profiles.TwoOrgsChannel
            jq: error: Profiles/0 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:
            .Profiles += FiveOrgsChannel, Profiles.TwoOrgsChannel
            jq: 2 compile errors
```

Comment: Can you post the output of `yq --version`?

Comment: You don't have to convert to JSON and modify the value with `jq` and write back as YAML. With mikefaraq/yq you can directly modify the YAML.

Comment: please find the version- yq version 3.3.2

Comment: Your question is not clear and the last edit even made it worse. Since you are new the site, you need to understand what makes a good question. 1. Need an exact input you are dealing with 2. Exact output expected 3. All the variable values (e.g. $1, $2) 4. tool versions (like you update for `yq`). See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

If you save the new "FiveOrgsChannel" profile section to a file named "newProfile.txt", you can just:

`$ cat newProfile.txt >> configtx.yaml`

This command will append the contents of newProfile.txt to the end of the configtx.yaml file.  For this particular use case, this should be acceptable, since the Profile section is the last section in configtx.yaml

Note: you will need to ensure that the newProfile.txt contains the correct indentation for the configtx.yaml file.  (In your example listed above, the indentation appears to be incorrect - FiveOrgsChannel should be at the same indent level as TwoOrgsChannel.)